# class method doesn't override class field

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, class-fields

Very weird behaviour. Why does the following log **"A.fn"** only, the next line **"B.fn"** doesn't even run? **What exactly is happening** in this following code?

I'm using **Babel stage-2**, which is used in most React projects.

```js
class A {
    fn = () => {
        console.log("A.fn");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    fn() {
        super.fn();
        console.log('B.fn')
    }
}

new B().fn(); // why this logs "A.fn" only, while "B.fn" isn't logged?
```

Comment: Is this with straight es6? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: it's perfectly valid es6 and runs well with babel transpiler

Comment: there is no babel tag and that's exactly what the comment above was trying to get to. For pure ES6, it would not be valid.

Comment: @JohnLee I think Phix means it requires at least stage-2 for the instance props. It isn't core ES6.

Comment: it runs perfectly on stage-2, added BabelJS tag

Comment: `fn` in `A` is an instance method while `fn` in `B` is a method on the prototype. The behavior then follows from how `extends` works together with name resolution order.

Comment: why `B.fn` isn't logged?

Comment: The prototype isn't checked because `fn` exists on the object itself already (the `fn` from `A`).

Comment: Isn't it because of arrow function (`fn = () = {...}`) in `A` class?

Comment: That's why you should not use class-field arrow functions as class methods.

Comment: @TheReason: It would be the same if it isn't an arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I know exactly what's happening in this following code?

Public class fields is equivalent to doing:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.fn = () =>  console.log("A.fn");
  }
}
```

I.e. `fn` is defined o*n the instance itself* whereas when using the method syntax, the method is defined *on the prototype* (`B.prototype.fn`). Lets log an instance of `B`:

[image]

The first `fn` is the one created in the constructor, the second one is the defined as `B`'s class methods. Because `fn` is defined on the instance, i.e. is "higher" in the prototype chain, it *shadows* `B.prototype.fn`, meaning that `B.prototype.fn` is never called.

**That's just how the prototype chain works!**

Here is a simpler example with the same problem:

```js
const proto = {fn() { console.log('proto'); }};
const obj = Object.create(proto);
obj.fn = () => console.log('instance');
obj.fn();
```

Comment: …and what is even worse about class fields: Using `fn = () => {` in the `class B` doesn't fix this.

Comment: `{fn() { console.log('proto'); }};` is not correct syntax..?

Comment: @JohnLee: Yes it is. Try to run the code snippet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions