# Inherited value overwriting getter

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I was messing around with classes when I found this weird behaviour:

```js
class A {
  test = 1
}

class B extends A {
  get test () {
    return 2
  }
}

const b = new B()

console.log(b.test)
```

The logical answer to the output should be `2` but when running the code, the output is `1`.

Am I missing something? Is this intended javascript behaviour? I could not find anything in the MDN documentation about this.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899900/why-the-getters-or-the-setters-are-not-inherited-independently-in-javascript) which might be related to mine but it did not include any work arounds.

Comment: `test = 1` is a field, i.e. a property on the _instance_. Getters will be placed on the prototype. Property access will check the instance (i.e. own properties) before the rest of the prototype chain.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477998/how-to-properly-override-an-accessor-getter-in-the-prototype-of-a-base-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477028/is-it-valid-to-override-a-property-in-the-javascript-typescript-base-class-with

Comment: Sorry for accidentally closing, it seems we have no proper canonical question for this. The closest would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805007/class-method-doesnt-override-class-field, but that explains it for methods not for getters

Answer (score 1):

You would have to redefine the value of `test` inside of `B`.

```js
class A {
  test = 1
}

class B extends A {
  test = 2 // redefine
}

const b = new B()

console.log(b.test) // 2
```

If you check out [*MDN - References - JavaScript - Functions - getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#description), you will see that this is not possible.

> ### *Description*
>
> …
> *Note the following when working with the get syntax:*
> …
>
> - *It must not appear with a data entry for the same property e.g. the following is forbidden*
>
>   ```js
>   {
>     x: /* … */, get x() { /* … */ }
>   }
>   ```

Comment: I think the note in MDN only applies to a property `x` on the _same object_ that would act as both an accessor property and a data property. In OP’s example, both of these exist, but not on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Mr. Polyshirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224/mr-polywhirl) and [Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon), it is not possible to overwrite an inherited property using a getter. My "solution" was to use plain-old functions instead of getters and setters.

So, for example, instead of using

```js
class Example {
  method = 'value'
}

const example = new Example()

console.log(example.method)
```

use

```js
class Example {
  #method = 'value'

  getMethod () {
    return this.#method
 }

 setMethod (method) {
   this.#method = method

   // Use return this to allow for method chaining
   return this
 }
}

const example = new Example()

console.log(example.getMethod())
```

or

```js
class Example {
  getMethod () {
    return 'value'
  }
}

const example = new Example()

console.log(example.getMethod())
```

Comment: You could actually use a proper accessor (getter/setter) property, since it is possible to overwrite the inherited getter/setter.